# Chrome desktop lets you force a password suggestion. Does Android Chrome support this too?

Tags: chrome-for-android, password

The frustrating problem of Chrome sometimes not automatically suggesting passwords (more an issue with the individual sites than Chrome I think) got a nice fix a while back.

On the desktop, I can right-click on the password text input and select "Suggest Password...":

[image]

But I'm on my phone a lot and would like to not have to open my laptop to register for a site. Is this supported on Android Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Suggest strong password" is available on Chrome for Android as explained [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7570435?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=0):

When you want to generate a secure password:

> 1. Turn on sync in Chrome.
> 2. Go to a website and sign up for an account.
> 3. Tap on the password text box.
> 4. Tap Suggest strong password.
>
>    - If you don't see this option, tap Password Save your password and then
>      Suggest strong password.
> 5. You'll see a preview of the password. To confirm, tap Use password.
> 6. Finish signing up for your account. Your password is automatically saved to Chrome.

However, there is an issue with newer versions of Chrome that does not allow the suggestion to appear as testified [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/191953520/android-not-suggesting-password-when-creating-accounts?hl=en) or [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/190516357/chrome-not-suggesting-passwords-for-new-sites) by many. As suggested on those links, removing the Chrome updates allows the suggestion message to appear.

On the left, when I uninstalled Chrome updates, on the right Chrome's latest version
[image] [image]

Suggested pasword on old version

[image]

You can also try to change your autofill service as suggested on one of the posted links.

Or you just wait for future versions to fix the issue.

Comment: Is there an open bug tracker for this?

Comment: @user1028270 I am not sure if a bug tracker was opened for this issue or not.